# How do I put two plots next to each other when having plots with different scales (twinaxes)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I have two plots but plotted on the same x-axis. I want to plot both plots next to each other (side by side), rather than vertically.
How might I do that?

Example data borrowed from matplotlib documentation. I tried this, and I got the first plot into the plt.subplots, but the second plot is still plotted below rather than beside the first one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create some mock data
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
data1 = np.exp(t)
data2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)


## initiating the plots next to each other 

fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
plt.xlim(0,4)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
plt.xlim(4,6)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to point out this,

- You generally don't plot after you do the `plt.show()`.

You can create all the `axes` first and then later use them. Refer below example.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create some mock data
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
data1 = np.exp(t)
data2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))

# create all axes we need
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = plt.subplot(122)
ax4 = ax3.twinx()

# share the secondary axes
ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax1, ax3)

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax1.grid()

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
plt.xlim(0,4)

color = 'tab:red'
ax3.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax3.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax3.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax3.grid()

color = 'tab:blue'
ax4.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax4.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
plt.xlim(4,6)

plt.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

**Output Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the easiest way is to use Gridspec for layout. The code in the graph is directly adapted from your code. On the other hand, I created the structure only. This structure can be extended in the future.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np

# Create some mock data
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
data1 = np.exp(t)
data2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=1, ncols=2, width_ratios=[1,1], wspace=0.5)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
plt.xlim(0,4)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
color = 'tab:red'
ax3.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax3.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax3.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax4 = ax3.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax4.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax4.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
plt.xlim(4,6)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you [need](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html).

Answer (score 1):

You actually need 4 plots here. So I used ax1 and ax2 for the plots on the left and ax3 and ax4 for the plots on the right. I'm not sure this is the best approach but I think it solves your problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create some mock data
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
data1 = np.exp(t)
data2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)


## initiating the plots next to each other 

fig,(ax1,ax3) = plt.subplots(1,2)

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2=ax1.twinx()

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax2.set_xlim([0,4])



color = 'tab:red'
ax3.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax3.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax3.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax4=ax3.twinx()

color = 'tab:blue'
ax4.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax4.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax4.set_xlim(4,6)



fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

[Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAygt.png)